# listfield with bitmap loaded from server

Tags: blackberry, user-interface, listfield

i have made a listfield with images, the listfield is parsed from online xml file.
it seems that downloading the images into the listfield is blocking the process of parsing the content of the listfield "text" , i want to show the content of the listfield "text" and then start to proccess the download of the images and then show the images.

**here is the code to call the downloader class:**

```
        Thread t = new Thread();
    {
        String imageFilename = imageurlStrin.substring(imageurlStrin.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        String saveDire = "file:///store/home/user/pictures/listfield/"+imageFilename;
        try {
        FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection)Connector.open(saveDire);
        if (fconn.exists()) {
         // do nothing
        }
        if (!fconn.exists()) {  
        UrlToImage bit = new UrlToImage(imageurlStrin);
        pic = bit.getbitmap();
        }
        }catch (Exception ioe) {
        System.out.println("error 18");
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

**and this is the downloader class code:**

```java
public class UrlToImage implements Runnable{
    String imageurlStrin=null;
    BitmapDowloadListener listener=null;
    public static Bitmap _bmap;
    private EncodedImage eih1;

    public void run() {

            UrlToImage bit = new UrlToImage(imageurlStrin);

    }


    public UrlToImage(String imageurlStrin)
    {
            HttpConnection connection = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            EncodedImage bitmap;

            byte[] dataArray = null;
            //byte[] data1 = null;

            try
            {
            connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(imageurlStrin, Connector.READ, true);
            inputStream = connection.openInputStream();
            byte[] responseData = new byte[10000];
            int length = 0;
            StringBuffer rawResponse = new StringBuffer();
            while (-1 != (length = inputStream.read(responseData)))
            {
            rawResponse.append(new String(responseData, 0, length));
            }
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
            throw new IOException("HTTP response code: "
            + responseCode);
            }

            final String result = rawResponse.toString();
            dataArray = result.getBytes();
            }
            catch (final Exception ex)
            { }

            finally
            {
            try
            {
            inputStream.close();
            inputStream = null;
            connection.close();
            connection = null;
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
            }

            bitmap = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(dataArray, 0,dataArray.length);
            // this will scale your image acc. to your height and width of bitmapfield

            int multH;
            int multW;
            int currHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
            int currWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
            int scrhi = Display.getWidth()/4;
            int scrwe = Display.getWidth()/4;

            multH= Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(currHeight),Fixed32.toFP(scrhi));//height
            multW = Fixed32.div(Fixed32.toFP(currWidth),Fixed32.toFP(scrwe));//width
            bitmap = bitmap.scaleImage32(multW,multH);

            Bitmap thefinal = bitmap.getBitmap();

            //url = StringUtils.replaceAll(url ,"http://u.bbstars.com/i-", "");
            final String imageFilename = imageurlStrin.substring(imageurlStrin.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

            String saveDire = "file:///store/home/user/pictures/listfield/"+imageFilename;
            String Dire = "file:///store/home/user/pictures/listfield/";

            JPEGEncodedImage finalJPEG = JPEGEncodedImage.encode(thefinal, 100);

            byte[] raw_media_bytes = finalJPEG.getData();
            int raw_length = finalJPEG.getLength();
            int raw_offset = finalJPEG.getOffset();

            FileConnection filecon = null;
            OutputStream out = null;

            try {
                    filecon = (FileConnection) Connector.open(Dire,Connector.READ_WRITE);
                    if(!filecon.exists()){
                            filecon.mkdir();
                    }
                    filecon = (FileConnection) Connector.open(saveDire,Connector.READ_WRITE);
                if(!filecon.exists()){
                    filecon.create();
                 }
                    out = filecon.openOutputStream();
                    out.write(raw_media_bytes, raw_offset, raw_length);
                    out.close();
                    filecon.close();
                    System.out.println("----------------file saved"+imageFilename);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("---------------===================- error saving the file");
                };
                try {
                    FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection)Connector.open(saveDire);
                    if (fconn.exists()) {
                        InputStream input = fconn.openInputStream();
                        int available = input.available();
                        final byte[] data1=IOUtilities.streamToBytes(input);
                        input.read(data1, 0, available);
                        eih1 = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data1,0,data1.length);
                    }
                }catch (Exception ioe) {
                        System.out.println("error gettin bitmap details from the piture");
                    }  
            _bmap=eih1.getBitmap();
            }
            public Bitmap getbitmap()
            {
            return _bmap;
            }
```

}

what should i do to prevent UI blocking, i want the perfect why to call that downloader class without stoping the process of parsing the other listfield content?

Comment: please paste your code into the question here, on stack overflow.  it's not that much code.  if you remove the extra blank lines from the second piece of code, and the `import` statements, it's really quite reasonable.

Comment: ok sir, thank you. what about the question ?

Comment: thank you Nate, i always accept answers if the realy help or at least give me a good step, you can check my profile. but some people don't even give a correct answers or they are far away from my question so you have to leave it even without voting down. please check my profile to make sure. And thank you sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may just have a simple syntax problem with the way you declared your thread object.  [See the BlackBerry documentation on Thread here](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/lang/Thread.html)

When you create a `Thread`, you normally either extend the `Thread` class with a subclass of your own, that implements the `run()` method, or you pass a new `Runnable` object in to the constructor of your `Thread` object.  In your code, you actually declare a `Thread` instance, and create it, but do not give it a `Runnable`, **or** override the default `run()` method.  So, this thread won't do *anything* in the background.

You have essentially declared a chunk of code within a *local scope*.  That's what happens if you just put some code within a set of curly brackets (`{` and `}`) that are not attached to anything:

```java
Thread t = new Thread();
// this next curly bracket starts a "local scope".  it is NOT part of Thread t!
{
    String imageFilename = imageurlStrin.substring(imageurlStrin.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    // The rest of your code here will not be executed on Thread t.  It will be executed
    // on the thread where you instantiate Thread t, right before you call t.start();
    // If this code is called on the main/UI thread (which it probably is), then the 
    // network request will block the UI thread, which will stop the loading of the rest
    // of the list.
};
t.start();
```

What you probably want is this:

```java
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        String imageFilename = imageurlStrin.substring(imageurlStrin.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        String saveDire = "file:///store/home/user/pictures/listfield/"+imageFilename;
        try {
            FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection)Connector.open(saveDire);
            if (fconn.exists()) {
                // do nothing
            }
            if (!fconn.exists()) {  
                UrlToImage bit = new UrlToImage(imageurlStrin);
                pic = bit.getbitmap();
            }
        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            System.out.println("error 18");
        }
    }

});

t.start();
```

Try that, and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you Nate,your code worked, and important thing is you gave me a good explanation about threading.It was something i was afraid of using it everything i make is in the same UI without external Threads. but today you have give me a good look for threading Thank you very much sir. `accepted` and `voted`

Comment: plus any one gonna use my code don't forget to make the thread sleep for 3 sec so it can get all the strings from the xml `Thread.sleep(3000);`
and all the thanks for Nale